# Grails update references

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

How can I add a Object to a relation and persist it ?

if i do something like that

```
registrationInstance.addToActionType(id:id)
```

I get an exception

```
Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_E7 ON PUBLIC.ACTION_TYPE_REGISTRATIONS(ACTION_TYPE_ID, REGISTRATION_ID)"; SQL statement: insert into action_type_registrations (action_type_id, registration_id) values (?, ?) [23001-147]
```

EDIT:

If I write

```
registrationInstance.addToActionType(ActionType.get(id))
```

I get the same Error, but it persists - so how can I get rid of that error?

EDIT2:

If I try to remove an object:

```
registrationInstance.removeFromActionType(ActionType.get(id))
```

I receve following error (sometimes, not allways)

```
Eindeutiger Index oder Primarschlüssel verletzt: "PRIMARY_KEY_E7 ON PUBLIC.ACTION_TYPE_REGISTRATIONS(ACTION_TYPE_ID, REGISTRATION_ID)" Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_E7 ON PUBLIC.ACTION_TYPE_REGISTRATIONS(ACTION_TYPE_ID, REGISTRATION_ID)"; SQL statement: update action_type_registrations set action_type_id=? where registration_id=? and action_type_idx=? [23001-147]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the object itself to the relationship:

```
registrationInstance.addToActionType(ActionType.load(id))
registrationInstance.save()
```

Comment: I'd use `ActionType.load(id)` instead; it doesn't retrieve the instance from the database but just creates a proxy. Since you're only setting the foreign key it's a lot cheaper than loading it and throwing it away.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's not detecting that the instance is already in the collection. Implement sensible `hashCode` and `equals` methods for `ActionType` so Hibernate can detect that it's already there and not try to create a duplicate record in the `ACTION_TYPE_REGISTRATIONS` join table.